# Laravel PHP: Updated Repository Interface file not being recognized

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am working with Eloquent repositories for a Laravel PHP project. I made a change to one of the declarations inside the interface file for a repository.  The problem is when I try to run my program, I keep getting a **'Declaration of Acme\repositories\Eloquent\EloquentPictureRepository::create() must be compatible with Acme\repositories\PictureRepository::create($input)'** error.

Right now my program is still reading the original declaration of 'PictureRepository.php' instead of the updated version I made to it.

**PictureRepository.php (Interface File):**

interface PictureRepository {

```
public function all();

public function find($id);

public function findOrFail($id);

/* I added the '$filename' parameter to the function 'create()' */

public function create($input, $filename);

public function update($id, $input);

public function delete($id);

public function forceDelete($id);

public function restore($id);

}
```

**EloquentPictureRepository:**

```
<?php namespace Acme\repositories\Eloquent;

use acme\repositories\PictureRepository;

use app\models\Picture;

class EloquentPictureRepository implements PictureRepository {

/* Added the new parameter to the 'create()' function */    

public function create($input, $filename)
{
    /* Need this structure in order for photos to actually be displayed. */

    $newPicture = new Picture;
    $newPicture->picture_name = $input['picture_name'];
    $newPicture->picture_path = $filename;
    $newPicture->picture_description = $input['picture_description'];
    $newPicture->picture_edges = $input['picture_edges'];
    $newPicture->picture_stones = $input['picture_stones'];
    $newPicture->picture_order = $input['picture_order'];
    $newPicture->picture_link = $input['picture_link'];
    $newPicture->picture_height = $input['picture_height'];
    $newPicture->picture_width = $input['picture_width'];
    $newPicture->category = $input['category'];
    $newPicture->picture_project = $input['picture_project'];
    return $newPicture->save();

}

}
```

I've tried running both 'php artisan dump-autoload' and 'composer update' but my new 'PictureRepository.php' file is still not being recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just ran 'composer dump-autoload' and now my updated repository file is recognized.

EDIT: Running 'composer dump-autoload' will actually affect your controllers and will not allow them to be updated.  Try not to run this command unless it is absolutely necessary.